# Not able to retrieve data from firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database Structure:

appname/users/userID/personal/Name

The child "name" is upadated in the database but is returning as null.

```
mChildReference =    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("personal"); //DatabaseReference

ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            User post = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: "+post.uname+"dob: "+post.udob+"phno: "+post.phone_number+"email: "+post.uemail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("RETRIEVED DATA", "Name: "+post.getUname()+"dob: "+post.getDob()+"phno: "+post.getPhone_number()+"email: "+post.getEmail());

            Log.e("DEBUG",dataSnapshot.getKey());
            fname.setText(post.getUname());

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.e("DEBUG", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    mChildReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);

    mPostListener = postListener;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the database is acting wierd, make sure you double-check your database rules. You can try to make them public for now. I find this useful when I am developing.

1. In the Firebase Console, click Database -> RULES
2. Set all permissions to public (Warning anyone
   can read and write!)

   ```
   // These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
   // read and write access to your database
   {
     "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
     }
   }
   ```
3. Try the query on Android again and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks...i'll try that but is there any other errors in the code because of which it is sending null values?